# What percentage of questions are answered on Stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

We all post questions and answers on Stackoverflow.com almost everyday. 
What percentage of them are answered? Accepted?

Just curious.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [Stack Exchange sites page](https://stackexchange.com/sites): 74%. This generally includes questions that have at least one upvoted answer and/or an accepted answer.

Comment: Great! I did't know about this page. Thanks!

Comment: That seems a lot...

Comment: @Trace 70% now. Going down.

Comment: @Trace 69% now. It's going down rather quickly tbh